# どれくらいかかる　ｖｓ　どれくらいかかりそう？

Tags: words

「どれくらい**かかるか**」と「どれくらい**かかりそうか**」の違いは何ですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the difference between a statement of fact and a statement of appearance/seem to (～そう). Note that the final か in both indicates that these are embedded clauses and can probably be followed by verbs like 分かる, 知る, etc.

> どれくらいかかるか ... the amount of time it will take

> どれくらいかかり**そう**か ... the amount of time **it seems like** it will take